# Change Combobox dropdown items to specific colors in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, colors, combobox

I'm currently trying to add a Combobox in a WPF Project. The Combobox will be used to Chose between multiple Colors. 
But how can i Change the Combobox items to specific Colors in XAML is my question?

I'm pretty sure how to do it in the actual Code but i would be glad if there'd be a way to "outsource" it into XAML instead.

Thanks to everyone in advance who will read/answer my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well ok somehow after hours of searching i just now found the answer....

so a simple

```
<ComboBoxItem Background="Orange">Orange</ComboBoxItem>
```

The question can be closed. Sorry. :D